# Getting the HTML of a website into a variable using the Request Library

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I'm using Node.JS with the Library "Request" and for some reason, I can't save the HTML from the request into a variable.

```
    var GarfHTML;
    Request(GarfURL, (error, response, body) => {
    GarfHTML = body;

    });

    console.log(GarfHTML);
```

I want to have it saved inside of the variable for use outside of the method, but the result returns as "undefined". When I do console.log inside of the Request method, the HTML is actually printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is executed before GarfHTMLis filled. Therefore when you try to access it, it might be still empty.These are Async functions. if you want to access it outside try

```
    Request(GarfURL, (error, response, body) => {
    let GarfHTML = body;
    triggered(GarfHTML);
    });

    function triggered(GarfHTML) {
    console.log(GarfHTML);
    // Do your work on GarfHTML
    }
```